# How to merge the all the callback results in final callback using Async parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have this scenario where I have to multiple CLI commands, which returns `JSON`, read each result and take the specific fields and finally merge them into a final `JSON`. All the CLI commands are independent each other.

```
var merge = require('./object-assign');

async.parallel(
  [
    function(callback) {
      var response = {},
          error {};
      var test = exec(command);

      test.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        response = data;
      });

      test.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        error.message = data;
      });

      test.on('close', function() {
        //callback1
        callback(error, response);
      })
    }, 

    function(callback) {
      var response = {},
          error {};
      var test = exec(command);
      test.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        response = data;
      });

      test.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        error.message = data;
      });

      test.on('close', function() {
        //callback2
        callback(error, response);
      })
    }
    //Few more callbacks 

  ], function(err, results) {
    //using object-assign to merge
    var test = merge(result[0], result[1]);
    //when callback1 completes result[0] is getting values where as result[1]
    //is undefined since it is getting executed.
  }
);
```

callback1 completes first and sends response to final callback with result, and callback2 completes and sends its response.
How make sure all callbacks are done in the final callback so that I can merge the result to get the final `JSON`?

Is async parallel the right approach here? If not, what is the best for this case?

Comment: It should already do what you're asking. it wan't reach the final callback until all the parallel function is resolved

Comment: did you check `err` variable? your `callback2` might have resulted in a error...

Answer (score 3):

Take a read at the Reference for **[async.js parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback)**

> Run the `tasks` array of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed. If any of the functions pass an error to its `callback`, the main `callback` is immediately called with the value of the error. Once the `tasks` have completed, the results are passed to the final `callback` as an `array`.
>
> **Note**: parallel is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about parallel execution of code. If your tasks do not use any timers or perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series. Any synchronous setup sections for each task will happen one after the other. JavaScript remains single-threaded.

Example:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.

    //manipulate the responses
    //JSON.stringify(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks much @jherax.I am not using either I/O tasks or timeouts,looks like it is executing in series.                                                                                 When I do console output : This is how i am getting output:
                                                                                                                 printing callback 1  - [corresponsing object];
results in final callback - [prints only callback1 values];
printing callback 2  - [corresponsing object];